# Como conectar ao banco de dados PostgreSql usando Xamarim

Tags: c#, xamarin

To criando uma aplicação Mobile usando o banco de dados PostgreSql, mas não to conseguindo abrir a conexão:

Meu código:

```
public class PgSql
{
    private string connString = "Server=192.168.1.5;Port=5432;User ID=postgres;Password=Kalisba987;Database=LotusERP;";
    private NpgsqlConnection conn;

    public string connect()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        thread.Start();
        string retorno;
        conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        try
        {
            this.conn.Open();
            retorno = "Conexão aberta com o banco PostgreSql";
        }
        catch (NpgsqlException ex)
        {
            retorno = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.conn.Close();
        }
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

O erro da toda vez na linha

```
conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
```

E aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1' threw an exception

Comment: Você está abafando a exceção no código dentro do **`catch`** e impossibilitando que a real mensagem seja mostrada para você. Este é um pequeno exemplo do que pode acontecer quando se usa o mecanismo de exceções de uma forma ruim. Remova o bloco `catch` e deixe a exceção fazer o seu trabalho, depois edite sua pergunta e adicione a real mensagem de erro.

Comment: Não é possível, somente através de um web service.

Comment: Não tem como dar esse erro nesse ponto do código a não ser que tenha um *bug* em `NpgsqlConnection()`, o que duvido. Não sei pra que criar uma *thread* que não está sendo usada, não sei o quanto isto está interferindo em enganar o que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Não é possível utilizar ainda NpgsqlConnection() no Xamarin, somente quando o mesmo der suporte ao .NET Standard. https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/451